How can I start a new bounty when the old bounty has expired?
How can I start a new bounty when the old bounty has expired?
Call Center Income halal or Haram?

I cannot see a button or option like "Start a bounty", well I have done it already, so I can't start it.

A question can only have one bounty on it at a time; you can't add a new bounty to a question until the old one has been awarded. If the bounty setter didn't manually award the bounty (i.e. there are no worthy answers) then the system will automatically do so and expire another 24 hours after the bounty ended.
